# Java annotation target ElementType.TYPE_USE on arrays

Tags: java, arrays, reflection, annotations, java-8

With the new Java 8's `ElementType.TYPE_USE` option, it is possible, amongst many other neat things, to annotate each component of an (multi-dimensional) array. For example, now I'm able to be annotate, in an simple array of String, both the whole type `String[]` and the inner component type `String`. So I'd expect to do something like this:

```
@MyAnnotation(0) private static (@MyAnnotation(1) String) [] strs0;
```

The way it has always been, I'd put the **annotation before the type**. If parenthesis were allowed in these expressions, then it would work flawlessly. However, it seems that Java chose another approach, that caused some problems. I have to write:

```
@MyAnnotation(0) private static String @MyAnnotation(1) [] strs1;
```

And assume that `@MyAnnotation(0)` applies to the **whole field**, and `@MyAnnotation(1)` just for the **`String`**, even though it is **after** the type `String`. Is that the correct interpretation of this declaration?

Because if so, then the reflection parsing goes terribly wrong. For example, take the following declaration:

```
@MyAnnotation(0) private static String @MyAnnotation(1) [] @MyAnnotation(2) [] @MyAnnotation(3) [] strs2;
```

One would assume that `@MyAnnotation(0)` refers to the whole field, then `@MyAnnotation(3)` refers to the `String[][]` component, `@MyAnnotation(2)` refers to the `String[]` component, and finally `@MyAnnotation(1)` refers to the `String` component. When we parse it, however, with the following code:

```
    Field field = Main.class.getDeclaredField("strs2");
    AnnotatedArrayType aat = (AnnotatedArrayType) field.getAnnotatedType();
    printAll(aat.getAnnotations());

    while (aat.getAnnotatedGenericComponentType() instanceof AnnotatedArrayType) {
        aat = (AnnotatedArrayType) aat.getAnnotatedGenericComponentType();
        printAll(aat.getAnnotations());
    }
```

We will see:

```
@MyAnnotation(1)
@MyAnnotation(2)
@MyAnnotation(3)
```

Contrary to the order we would expect (`{ 3, 2, 1 }`). This is particularly a hassle if we were to iterate over the matrix's elements and at the same time iterate throw the annotations, applying them to the corresponding elements. When we iterate, we go though the last level to the first, that is, we go through all `String[][][]` getting each `String[][]`. Then we go over each `String[][]` and get all `String[]`. Finally we iterate over `String[]`, and get each `String`.

These reflections (no pun intended) led me to think whether my interpretations of the meaning of these TYPE_USE examples are correct. Of course I could just iterate once though the matrix, stack the annotation pairs and re-work then around, but Java is always so simple and elegant that there must be something I am missing, being the way we declared the expression or in the way the whole thing is meant to be interpreted.

The reason I want to annotate each array component is to make a validation framework. It works flawlessly on the `List<>` type, using the `AnnotatedParameterizedType`. I can write `@Required List<@Required List<@Required Map<@Required String, @Required String>>> data` and retrieve those annotations in the correct other, no problems at all. Oddly, the primitive arrays seem to behave differently...

**More details, updated with answer information**

For example, when we write

```
@A List<@B ArrayList<@C LinkedList<@D Integer>>> matrix;
```

It is very clear that `@A` relates to the outermost `List`, `@B -> ArrayList`, `@C -> LinkedList` and `@D -> Integer`, because the annotation is just before the type **declared**. But when we write

```
@A int @B [] @C [] @D [] matrix;
```

In a first look, the annotation seem to be after the type, for example:

```
@A (((int @B) [] @C) [] @D) [] matrix;
```

And so `@B -> int`, `@C -> int[]` and `@D -> int[][]`. The thing is, we have to look it this way:

```
@A int (@B []) (@C []) (@D []) matrix;
```

And then if we know that when we call matrix[x], we get a int[][], so @B -> int[][], whereas only matrix[x][y][z] gives a int, so @D -> int. So the co-relation is in the **usage** of the field, not the declaration instruction.

This is different of the way with the `List`s, because there the `@D` annotation is just before the `Integer` type it refers to. This discrepancy maybe only makes sense for generic lists, and probably doesn't occur in other common Generic scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong. Given a `String[][][]`, you describe it as an array, where the component is a `String[][]`. That is also an array, where the component is a `String[]`. That is also an array, where the component is a `String`.

> One would assume that `@MyAnnotation(0)` refers to the whole field, then
>   `@MyAnnotation(3)` refers to the `String[][]` component, `@MyAnnotation(2)`
>   refers to the `String[]` component, and finally `@MyAnnotation(1)` refers
>   to the String component.

I don't agree. So, given a

```
@MyAnnotation(0) private static String @MyAnnotation(1) [] @MyAnnotation(2) [] @MyAnnotation(3) [] strs2;
```

you describe it as a field annotated with `@MyAnnotation(0)` which is of an array type, where the component is a `String[][]` annotated with `@MyAnnotation(1)`. That is also an array, where the component is a `String[]` annotated with `@MyAnnotation(2)`. That is also an array, where the component is a `String` annotated with `@MyAnnotation(3)`.

> When we iterate, we go though the **last level to the first**, that is, we
>   go through all String[][][] getting each String[][]. Then we go over
>   each String[][] and get all String[]. Finally we iterate over
>   String[], and get each String

That's what seems backwards.

Comment: If @(1) -> String[][], @(2) -> String[] and @(3) -> String, as you said, the order retrieved would make sense indeed, but I can't see that relation in the declaration expression. If I wrote just `String @MyAnnotation(1) [] @MyAnnotation(2) [] matrix;`, I am to assume @(1) -> String[] and @(2) -> String? I can't seem to understand this placement logic... In my way I see it like this: `((String @MyAnnotation(1)) [] @MyAnnotation(2)) [] matrix;`, so @(1) -> String and @(2) -> String[]. How do I group the annotations with their types in your way?

Comment: @LuanNico I don't get it. The declaration is `String[this one contains arrays of strings][this one contains strings]`.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I was trying to group them like I said, but the correct way is simply `String (@MyAnnotation(1) []) (@MyAnnotation(2) []) matrix;`, and to understand it one must remember that when you index, `String[contains String[]s][contains Strings]`. I was thinking that the annotation for the inner most type should have been together with the `String` word, and so forth outwards, but I should consider how I access the field, rather than the declaration. It all makes sense now. It is the opposite of generics, though, when working with List<>s, that caused my confusion.

Comment: @luan If you would post your generics code, maybe I can help make a parallel, if there is one.

Comment: Updated the question with more details about my confusion and the discrepancy to the API with generics.

Comment: @LuanNico I see now what you meant. You can declare `int[][] num;` as `int num[][];`. What do you make of that?